# Compare month and day of date in string to month and day of the current date

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, date, comparison

I have a JSON object that has several dates, for example: 15/12/2005 or 14/12/2012.

I need to do a comparison of the month and day with today's month and day; the year does not matter. I'm doing this:

```
-(void)setSingle:(NSDictionary*)object name:(NSString*)name {

    NSMutableDictionary * content = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:name]];

    NSLog(@"%@", name);

    if(name == @"teste") {
        NSDate *dateReturn = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];

        NSString * tempDate;
        NSDictionary *dateObjectTemp = nil;
        NSDictionary * dateObject = [object objectForKey:name];

        for (NSDictionary*g in dateObject) {
            tempDate = [g objectForKey:@"dia"];
            dateObjectTemp = g;

            NSLog(@"Data: %@", tempDate);

            dateReturn = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tempDate];

            NSLog(@"Data: %@", dateReturn);
            [content setObject:dateObjectTemp forKey:tempDate];
        }

    } else {
        NSDate *dateReturn = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

        NSString * tempDate;
        NSDictionary *dateObjectTemp = nil;
        NSDictionary * dateObject = [object objectForKey:name];

        for (NSDictionary*g in dateObject) {
            tempDate = [g objectForKey:@"dia"];
            dateObjectTemp = g;

            dateReturn = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tempDate];
            [content setObject:dateObjectTemp forKey:tempDate];
        }
    }

    NSDictionary* cont =content;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:name];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cont forKey:name];

}
```

This picks up the date, but `dataReturn` returns 2000-12-15. I want only the day and month.

and when will compare the next method

```
-(void)showContent{

    if ( [self daysBetweenDate:currentDate andDate:self.dateLimit]>=0 ) {

        NSDictionary *santododia  = [super compareDate:currentDate name:@"santos"];
        [self defineContent:[santododia objectForKey:@"texto"]];

        self.urlShare = [santododia objectForKey:@"url"];
        self.tituloShare = [santododia objectForKey:@"titulo"];
    }else{
        [self.webView loadHTMLString: @"<font color='black' style='font-family:sans-serif;'>Conteúdo indisponível, escolha a data de hoje ou anterior</font>" baseURL:nil];
    }
}
```

Although the current date matches, the test is not passing.

```
-(void) defineContent:(NSString *)string{

    string = [parentClass checkStringContent:string];
    NSLog(@"Teste: %@", string);
    if(string.length == 0){
       string = @"<font color='black' style='font-family:sans-serif;'>nothing</font>";
    } else {
        string =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", string , @"<style>body {color:#000 !important} .day{margin-top:5px} .month{margin-top:5px}  </style>" ];
    }

    [self.webView loadHTMLString: string baseURL:nil];

}
```

Comment: set the date formatter as    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];   Then it'll work fine.

Comment: but I do not want to use the year. Allow me to elaborate. I have a text 12/15/2015 day and another day 16/12/2002, If you notice are different years, but what matters and the day and month, forever will display on all days 16/12 text, not matter year

Answer (score 0):

To compare only parts of a date, you should use [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateComponents). Parse your strings into `NSDate`s using `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSString * jsonDateString = @"15/12/2005";
NSDateFormatter * dF = [NSDateFormatter new];
// Format string must match date string!
dF.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyy";

NSDate * testDate = [dF dateFromString:jsonDateString];
NSDate * today = [NSDate date];
```

From there, you use [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/) to [decompose that date](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW7) and today's date into the pieces you're interested in:

```
NSCalendar * cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * todayComps = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay
                                       fromDate:today];
NSDateComponents * testComps = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay
                                      fromDate:testDate];
```

Then you can compare those date components objects:

```
[testComps isEqual:todayComps]
```

if the result is `YES`, then the two dates have the same day and month, ignoring the all other parts of the date, including the year.

Answer (score -1):

try this to compare date -

```
NSDate *minDate ;
NSDate *maxDate ;

NSComparisonResult compareStart = [minDate compare: self.selectedDate]; // date1 is 6/6/2011 00:00
NSComparisonResult compareEnd = [maxDate compare: self.selectedDate];   // date2 is 9/6/2011 00:00

if ( ( (compareStart == NSOrderedAscending) || (compareStart == NSOrderedSame) ) && (compareEnd == NSOrderedDescending))
{
    NSLog(@"date is in the right range");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Range is not valid .");
}
```